# custom tiles in primefaces GMap component

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, google-maps-api-2

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a GMap component in primefaces which use custom tiles to render the map. I know how to do it in pure javascript (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_custommap1.htm):

```
var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
var copyright = new GCopyright(1,new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(53.8136257,-3.0981445),new GLatLng(53.8654855,-2.9663944) ),14, "Ordnance Survey");
var copyrightCollection = new GCopyrightCollection('Map Data:');
copyrightCollection.addCopyright(copyright);

CustomGetTileUrl=function(a,b){
   return "tiles/"+a.x+"_"+a.y+".jpg"
}
var tilelayers = [new GTileLayer(copyrightCollection,14,14)];
tilelayers[0].getTileUrl = CustomGetTileUrl;
var custommap = new GMapType(tilelayers, new GMercatorProjection(15), "Old OS");
map.addMapType(custommap);

map.setCenter(new GLatLng(53.852,-3.038), 14, custommap);
```

But I have no idea how to do it in primefaces.

If it is not possible, do you know maybe how the GMap component should be modified by javascript to replace getTileUrl?

### Edit

As Duncan noticed the code above is v2 (my original code is v3, but is really messy, so I took the first working snippet from Internet without checking the version...), the full v3 code should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions= {
            center : new  google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            rotateControl : true,
            panControl : true,
            zoom : 2,
            streetViewControl : false,
            mapTypeControlOptions : {
                mapTypeIds : ['cv0']
            }
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var option = {
            getTileUrl : function(coord, zoom) {
                var tileRange = 15;
                if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= tileRange || coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= tileRange) {
                    return null;
                }
                var addr = "../map_images/new7778069575062411171/5/" + coord.x + "," + coord.y + ".PNG";
                return addr;
            },
            tileSize : new google.maps.Size(256,256),
            maxZoom : 2,
            minZoom : 2,
            name : "title"
        };
        map.mapTypes.set('cv0', new google.maps.ImageMapType(option));
        map.setMapTypeId('cv0');
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is [API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), which is deprecated and due to stop working later this year (was going to be May 19th, extended until November). Strongly suggest rewriting it to API v3 soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the full working code that I was looking for:

```
<h:head>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function test(){
    var zzz = gmtls.getMap();
    var option = {
        getTileUrl : function(coord, zoom) {
            var tileRange = 15;
            if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= tileRange || coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= tileRange) {
                return null;
            }
            var addr = "../map_images/new7778069575062411171/5/" + coord.x + "," + coord.y + ".PNG";
            return addr;
        },
        tileSize : new google.maps.Size(256,256),
        maxZoom : 2,
        minZoom : 2,
        radius : 360,
        name : "title"
    };
    cvMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(option);
    zzz.mapTypes.set('cv0', cvMapType);
    zzz.setMapTypeId('cv0');
}
//]]>

    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="test();">
    <center>
        <h:form>  
            <p:gmap widgetVar="gmtls" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" 
                        style="width:600px;height:400px" />
        </h:form>  
    </center>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Mark as answer to close you question :)

Comment: I cannot flag the answer - the button remains disabled... Maybe as a new user I cannot do it... (there are no hints, why it is disabled)

Answer (score 0):

`Primefaces's gmap` has `widgetVar` attribute, you can get `gmap` in `javascript` by it:

```
<h:head>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            var zzz = gmtls.getMap();                   
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="test();">
  <h:form id="description"> 
    <p:gmap widgetVar="gmtls" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" 
                        style="width:600px;height:400px" />                
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Note:** Primefaces use API v3.

Comment: sure, I will do it, but before I would like to post the full code (I cannot do it for 4 hours as I am a new user...)